# pySpark output file with timestamp name

Tags: pyspark, timestamp

**I need to name my outputfile with the timestamp but getting an error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong**

```
timestamp = spark.sql("select string(date_format(current_timestamp,'yyyy/MM/dd_HH:mm:ss'))").collect()[0][0]
print(timestamp)
```

```
Error: ADLException: Error getting info for file 
/06/05_13:14:01
```

**no error if I use current date instead of timestamp. But I need timestamp**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some caracters are not allowed in file naming:

`#L1234_ABC123_2020/06/05_13:14:01` is not vaide. Try something like `#L1234_ABC123_20200605_131401` for example, or with underscore `_`. colons `:` are not allowed basically.

Comment: so simply change my timestamp ":"